# How to write character string to serial port using SerialPort.Write(String)

Tags: c#, string, serial-port, ascii

Im trying to write a string to the serial port using SerialPort.Write(String).
So far i try it like followed

I instantiate the serial port object in my constructor.
EDIT: Setting the port parameters solved the problem.

```
public CSerialPort()
{
    this._serialPort = new SerialPort("COM6",1200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
    this._serialPort.DataReceived += OnSerialPortDataReceived;
}
```

I open the port:

```
public void OpenSerialPort()
{
    try
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Trying to open Serial Port: {0}", this._serialPort.PortName);
        this._serialPort.Open();
        this.PortIsOpen = true;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Trying to open Serial Port: {0}", ex);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Trying to open Serial Port: {0}", ex);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Trying to open Serial Port: {0}", ex);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        _logger.DebugFormat("Trying to open Serial Port: {0}", ex);
    }
}
```

And i try to send the content of a string via the serial port:

```
public void WriteToSerialPort(string writeBuffer)
{
    this._serialPort.Write(writeBuffer);
}
```

Where the content of the String is:

```
this._serialPort.WriteToSerialPort("ABC");
```

My problem is that on the receiving side (another PC with a serial port monitoring software) i dont receive the "ABC".
What i receive is "þ" which is ASCII character code 254.

I tried to change the Encoding property to all available encodings, but that didn't help.

Can anybody tell me what i can do to send any character string to the serial port using the serial port class?
Did i miss or misunderstand anything?

Comment: You need to define what kind of string is expected on another side - ASCII string or something else, with null in the end or not. Your code doesn't contain port settings, like baud rate. If another side works with different port parameters, result is undefined.

Comment: Alex, the other side requires/awaits an ASCII string. I will set the parameters and try. THX

Comment: It is better to work with `SerialPort.Write(Byte[], Ini32, Int32)` overload which doesn't depend on any string encoding settings. Prepare byte array according to another side requirements.

Comment: Simple as that, but you saved my day. I set the parameters and it works. I forgot that i set the baud rate on the other side to 1200. So it didn't work with the default baud rate. I will also try to implement your hint for  SerialPort.Write(Byte[], Ini32, Int32). THX a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
byte[] MyMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.getBytes(yourString);

MySerialPort.Write(MyMessage,0,MyMessage.Length);
```

you may also want to check your **BAUD rate** on both sides of the connection (these need to be the same).